# what will i do to resolve this error "emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling activity launch'!"?

Tags: android, eclipse

i had tried all my best efforts to resolve this error but i am still struck would anybody help me please??
emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'com.hellos.ArithmaticCalculatorActivity activity launch'!
i did not find any devices in the devices. is there any way i can resolve these error?

Comment: Is it showing while u r running your project ?

Comment: @hassan can you capture your screen short?

Comment: i can not capture the screenshot....:(

Comment: yes it shows while i am running it, a few days earlier it was working right biut now it is not

Comment: I usually restart the emulator when that happens.

Comment: simply restart your emulator or Eclipse.

Comment: i had restarted it twice. even i wrote mine program and make a new avd but all in vain......:(

Comment: replace your adt plugin. and make sure that you restart your system after uninstalling and installing adt...

Comment: how would i replace mine adt? please help me a bit. i am new in android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same error .. solution below worked for me

check the link:

[android-emulator-5554-disconnected](http://phonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/09/android-emulator-5554-disconnected.html)

Hope it helps.

Comment: i had already enabled the wipe data. i think i have to reinstall the ide, it might help?